# Which books cover the concept of Imagination and Creativity in Chess?

Tags: books, psychology

I came across two books on Creativity & Imagination in Chess. Are there other books that cover the topics?

- Imagination in Chess by Paata Gaprindashvili
- Creative Chess by Amatzia Avni

Answer (score 2):

Two much older (dating from the 50's and 60's) books which cover these topics under the general banner of psychology are *Psychology in Chess* by Nicolai Krogius and *The Chess Mind* by Gerald Abrahams.

Recognising that imagination can have its down side, Abrahams has a chapter in his book called "*Imagination: Its Use and Abuse*".

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Brian Towers's answer I would also like to add some more:

1. [Creative chess strategy by Alfonso Romero](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1901983927)
2. [Creative Chess Opening Preparation: How to Seize the Initiative and Pose Novel Problems for the Opponent by Viascheslav Eingorn](https://www.ebay.com/itm/284663685642?chn=ps&mkevt=1&mkcid=28&srsltid=AfAwrE7qctWCfu4GTWR3XlRheWcQNaCpZ1vWi1E0J5vB45ND19dVEOw8rYg)